# Drawing an "encoder--decoder architecture" in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the encoder--decoder architecture of the [ACL'16 tutorial](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/nmt/Luong-Cho-Manning-NMT-ACL2016-v4.pdf) in TikZ (pp. 15 of the linked PDF).

[image]

However, I am absolutely lost as to how to

- Make things "flow" along the same line vertically, and
- Adjust the sizes of the trapeziums and the rectangle in the middle.

Some of the stuff I've tried:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[trapezium, draw, rotate=270] (encoder) {Encoder};
  \node[left=of encoder.center] (input) {Input text};
  \draw[->] (input) -- (encoder);
  \node[rectangle, draw, right=of encoder.center] {\begin{tabular}{S}-0.2 \\ -0.1 \\ 0.1 \\ 0.4 \\ -0.3 \\ 1.1\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would say it is an OK-ish way to go, but I do not know how to align the side of the trapezium to that of the rectangle, and I think that the way I'm centering things vertically is cumbersome.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but the definition of `trapezium` is missing, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
{
  myTrapezium/.pic =
  {
    \draw [fill=magenta!50] (0,0) -- (0,\b) -- (\a,\c) -- (\a,-\c) -- (0,-\b) -- cycle ;
    \coordinate (-center) at (\a/2,0);
    \coordinate (-out) at (\a,0);
  },
  myArrows/.style=
  {
    line width=2mm, 
    red,
    -{Triangle[length=1.5mm,width=5mm]},
    shorten >=2pt, 
    shorten <=2pt, 
  }
}
    \def\a{3}  % width of trapezium
    \def\b{.9} % small height of trapezium
    \def\c{2}  % tall height of trapezium

\begin{tikzpicture}
[
  node distance=1mm, % space between drawn parts
  every node/.style={align=center},
]


  \node (middleThing) 
  [
    draw,
    fill=purple!80!blue!70,
    %minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=2*\b cm,
    font=\tiny,
  ]
  {\begin{tabular}{r}-0.2 \\ -0.1 \\ 0.1 \\ 0.4 \\ -0.3 \\ 1.1\end{tabular}};
  \pic (right)[right=of middleThing.east] {myTrapezium} ;
  \pic (left)[left=of middleThing.west, rotate=180] {myTrapezium} ;
  \node at (right-center) {Decoder} ;
  \node at (left-center) {Encoder};
  \node at (right-center) {Decoder} ;

  \def\d{.9}
  \coordinate (u) at (\d,0);
  \draw [myArrows] (right-out) -- ++(u) node [anchor=west] {Translated\\text};
  \draw [myArrows] ($(left-out)-(u)$) node [anchor=east] {Input\\text} -- ++(u) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution. As [marsupilam](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374954/1952), we start with the central body

```
\node[fill=brown!90!black, text=white, font=\sffamily\small, inner sep=2pt] (a) 
     {\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}-0.2\\-0.1\\0.1\\0.4\\-0.3\\1.1\end{tabular}};
```

which is used to fix the height of decoder and encoder. Both are defined as `fit` nodes with a forced minimum width.

```
\node[fit=(a.north) (a.south), inner sep=1pt, right=1mm of a, minimum width=2cm, 
       label=center:Decoder] (dec) {};
```

This command prints encoder/decoder but also defines their anchors which are used to fill the trapezoidal area on a background layer

```
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[cyan!30] (dec.north west)--([yshift=5mm]dec.north east)--
               ([yshift=-5mm]dec.south east)--(dec.south west)--cycle;
```

After that we only need two `arrow` shape nodes an two rectangular nodes to complete the scheme.

[image]

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, backgrounds, fit, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node[fill=brown!90!black, text=white, font=\sffamily\small, inner sep=2pt] (a) {\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}-0.2\\-0.1\\0.1\\0.4\\-0.3\\1.1\end{tabular}};

\node[fit=(a.north) (a.south), inner sep=1pt, right=1mm of a, minimum width=2cm, label=center:Decoder] (dec) {};
\node[fit=(a.north) (a.south), inner sep=1pt, left=1mm of a, minimum width=2cm, label=center:Encoder] (enc) {};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[cyan!30] (dec.north west)--([yshift=5mm]dec.north east)--([yshift=-5mm]dec.south east)--(dec.south west)--cycle;
\fill[cyan!30] (enc.north east)--([yshift=5mm]enc.north west)--([yshift=-5mm]enc.south west)--(enc.south east)--cycle;
\end{scope}

\node[right=1mm of dec, fill=blue, single arrow] (b) {\phantom{a}};
\node[align=left, right=1mm of b] {Translated\\ text};

\node[left=1mm of enc, fill=blue, single arrow] (c) {\phantom{a}};
\node[align=left, left=1mm of c] {Input\\ text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `trapezium`.

Trapezium size: You can adjust the sizes of the trapeziums and the rectangle in the middle with `minimum width=<...>` , `minimum height=<...>`. To rotate t the object `shape border rotate=90` would help. Useful `trapezium right angle=85`, `trapezium left angle=85` see [67.3 Geometric Shapes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=de) on page 696. ``

The rectangle could be created with `\node [rectangle]`.

With `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` you can use `right=of` etc to place the different nodes.

Color definition with the RGB values:

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{226,185,252}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{140,21,21} 
\definecolor{mycolor3}{RGB}{86,1,141}
```

Arrow: Have a look to [67.5 Arrow Shapes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=de) on page 717. Without text you should add a `minimum height=<...>`.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{226,185,252}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{140,21,21} 
\definecolor{mycolor3}{RGB}{86,1,141} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings,shapes,arrows,fit}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{trapezium stretches=true}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [trapezium, fill=mycolor!100, minimum width=72mm , minimum height=62mm,shape border rotate=270,trapezium right angle=86,trapezium left angle=86, anchor = east,font=\sffamily\small,inner sep=0pt] (E) at (0,0)  {\Huge Encoder};
\node [rectangle, fill=mycolor2!100, text=white,font=\sffamily\Large,minimum height=40mm,right=2.5mm of E,text width=15mm, anchor = west, align=center] (M) {\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}-0.2 \\ -0.1 \\ 0.1 \\ 0.4 \\ -0.3\\ 1.1\end{tabular}};
\node [trapezium, fill=mycolor!100, minimum width=72mm , minimum height=62mm,shape border rotate=90,trapezium right angle=86,trapezium left angle=86,right=22.5mm of M, anchor = west,font=\sffamily,inner sep=0pt] (D) at (0,0) {\Huge Decoder};
\draw [red, <->] (E.bottom left corner) -- (E.bottom right corner)
node [midway, below right] {width};
\draw [red, <->] (E.top side) -- (E.bottom side)
node [at start, above] {height};
%
\node[left=4mm of E,single arrow, draw,minimum height=6mm,fill=mycolor3](al) {};
\node[align=left, left=3mm of al,font=\sffamily] {Input\\ text};
%
\node[right=4mm of D,single arrow, draw,minimum height=6mm,fill=mycolor3](ar) {};
\node[align=left, right=3mm of ar,font=\sffamily] {Translated\\ text};
%%
%\foreach \anchor/\placement in
%{north west/above left, north/above, north east/above right,
%west/left, center/above, east/right,
%mid west/right, mid/above, mid east/left,
%base west/left, base/below, base east/right,
%south west/below left, south/below, south east/below right,
%text/left, 10/right, 130/above}
%\draw[shift=(E.\anchor),green] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)}
%node[\placement] {\scriptsize\texttt{(E.\anchor)}};
%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```